# WordPress No sound in header youtube video on Frontpage

Tags: wordpress, header

i try to use `the_custom_header_markup();` in my theme for create a video loop in the top of the page like appears in the base theme tweetySeventeen and i can't figured how turn on the video sound.

Comment: Please keep [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in your mind even when posting self Q&As. Your question is vague, too broad and ultimately off-topic. Consider editing the question and including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if applicable. You should ask a question that can be answered by others, think of it like that. Posting an answer based on what you have found yourself is always welcome, but that does not mean that expected question quality should not be met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the video is controlled with the file `/wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js`

for customize them in your theme you need overwrite this file.

1. Copy this file to your assets, from the root of your website write

   cp wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js wp-content/themes/[Your Theme]/assets/js/wp-custom-header.js
2. register the new file in `[Your Theme]/functions.php`  adding this code

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_header_script' );

   function register_header_script() {
   wp_deregister_script( 'wp-custom-header');
   wp_register_script( 'wp-custom-header', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/wp-custom-header.js'), array( 'jquery-masonry' ), false, 1 );
   }
3. Now we can control the video in many ways, to turn on the sound in our file `wp-custom-header.js` search and delete the line  `e.target.mute();` (line 390 in wordpress 4.9.8 or line 394 in WordPress 5.5.1)

before

```
            handler.player = new YT.Player( video, {
            height: this.settings.height,
            width: this.settings.width,
            videoId: this.settings.videoUrl.match( VIDEO_ID_REGEX )[1],
            events: {
                onReady: function( e ) {
                    e.target.mute();
                    handler.showControls();
                }, ...
```

after

```
        handler.player = new YT.Player( video, {
            height: this.settings.height,
            width: this.settings.width,
            videoId: this.settings.videoUrl.match( VIDEO_ID_REGEX )[1],
            events: {
                onReady: function() {
                    // e.target.mute();
                    handler.showControls();
                }, ...
```

Exist many other header's video functionalities than you can customize in this file.

Enjoy !